# Grant group global permissions similar to sonar-administrators

Tags: sonarqube

I create a SonarQube group `sonar-administrators-ldap` and mapped to LDAP `sonar-administrators-ldap`. Users under `sonar-administrators-ldap` are able to login successfully.

When navigate to `http://localhost:9000/roles/global`, it only shows two default groups: `Anyone` and `sonar-administrators`, but not the new `sonar-administrators-ldap` group.

How do I grant/revoke global permissions for groups other the default groups?

Comment: The Global Permissions Admin page is precisely the place where you can [grant/revoke permissions](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authorization#Authorization-GlobalPermissions) to users/groups (just click on the small blue list icon next within each permission to add users/groups). Can you clarify what doesn't work in your case ?

Comment: @Nicolas, the "All" "Users" "Groups" links in Global Permissions Admin page don't seem to function correctly. When select "Users" it shows "No results". When select "All", only showing two built-in groups: Anyone and sonar-administrators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create additional groups(similar to "sonar-administrators") with admin permissions.

Create a new Group with the same name as displayed in your AD.Restart the sonar to pick up the changes.Grant the new group admin permissions using the sonar API.

```
curl -X POST -v -u admin:Password 'http://mysonar/api/permissions/add_group?permission=admin&groupName=mynewgroup'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use sonarqube global permission UI, but [it's not intuitive at all](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-8019). The `Global Permissions` (https://my.sonar.com/admin/permissions) page shows you only groups that have been granted any permissions already.

In order to be able to add permission to existing groups, you need to search it, for example:

[image]

Only then the group will appear and you will be able to add the desired permission.

Comment: Wow.. this cost me like an hour or so.. really bad UX