# Insufficient privileges when uploading to sonarqube.com

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to upload the sonar analysis for my open-source project to sonarqube.com but am getting Insufficient privileges:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar (default-cli) on project metrics-transport-parent: Insufficient privileges -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar (default-cli) on project metrics-transport-parent: Insufficient privileges
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Insufficient privileges
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:36)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:80)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute(SonarQubeMojo.java:139)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: Insufficient privileges
```

The following are the steps I have completed:

1. Logged into sonarqube.com via github
2. Generated a User-Token
3. Added the following maven properties:

   sonar.host.url=https://sonarqube.com

   sonar.login=token
4. Ran the build with sonar:sonar

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to specify the organization into which you want to push your project - using the following parameter:

```
sonar.organization=...
```

Please note that this is described on the ["Get Started" page](http://about.sonarqube.com/get-started/):

[image]

Comment: I initially followed this blog: https://about.sonarqube.com/news/2016/09/01/sonarqubedotcom-open-to-aynone.html . There was no mention of organization. But the Get Started page is clear.

Comment: The links no longer work... how would I get / create an organization key?

Comment: Never mind.. I did not need a key. I had to add permissions as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51297702/880619 It was really impossible to find that option.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the root cause was trying to upload the sonar result to **non-existing git branch**

```
-Dsonar.branch=NON_EXISTING_GIT_BRANCH
```

Hint:
`sonar.branch` is deprecated, and you should use `sonar.branch.name`